# Vs Code is showing syntax error in every program

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

While I am trying to run my programs in vs code in python terminal it shows an error like this =

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe e:/python/table.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: What does the code look like?

Comment: How are we supposed to help with an error in your code if you do not show your code?

Comment: @CoryKramer I usually use the Crystal Mirror extension. It reflects the source code from far far away to my VSC edtor

Comment: That's not python code. Looks like a line from a Windows batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same error content: No matter which script with the correct code is run, the console displays this content.

[image]

Reason: The reason is that the python console of my current VSCode terminal has entered the python interactive window.

Solution: Enter "`exit()`" in the console to exit it.

If this is not what you want, please describe in detail and let me know.